# Замена fragment view по клику

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-layout, view

Может не совсем верный вопрос, перегуглил все что можно, но так и нашел решения. Суть в следующем: есть фрагмент управления плеером подключенный к сервису и 2 вьюшки - краткая и полная, необходимо, чтобы отображение сворачивалось и разворачивалось из краткой в полную по клику, каким образом это реализовать как можно правильнее и менее требовательно к ресурсам для быстрой обработки.

[image: Views]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Поместите оба варианта отображения в разметку фрагмента
2. Назначьте одному из них `android:visibility="gone"`
3. По клику меняйте видимость разных вариантов разметки с `View.VISIBLE` на `View.GONE` так:

   ```
   someViewToSwitchLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            firstLayoutVariant.setVisibility(firstLayoutVariant.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE?  View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            secondLayoutVariant.setVisibility(secondLayoutVariant.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE?  View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
   });
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, так и думал сделать, но думал это по-колхозному)